# cannot convert from 'P.CoffeeShopDBEntities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

Tags: c#

I tried to recreate a code (that I've seen in a video) in Visual Studio 2013 (c#) that was written in VS2008 (c#): 
I've tried both EF 6 and EF 5 version options same result..searched web and MSDN with no luck.

Here is my code with comments showing the errors I got:

---

```
 private CoffeeShopDBEntities cse = new CoffeeShopDBEntities();

        private void AddProductsToTabbedPanel()
        {

           // using (CoffeeShopDBEntities context = new CoffeeShopDBEntities()) 
     //--found this on msdn..got rid of old but end up w/2 new errors see below
      {
   //the foreach code below goes here
    }


            foreach(TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {

                ObjectQuery<tblProduct> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<tblProduct>
                    ("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P", cse);

                //when 'context' used 1)possible mistaken empty statment 
                //2)the name 'context' doesnt exist in the current context

                //when 'cse'used :
                //Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<P.tblProduct>.ObjectQuery(string, System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext)' has some invalid arguments    
                //Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'P.CoffeeShopDBEntities' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

           foreach (tblProduct tprod in filteredProduct)
                 {
                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.Text = tprod.Description;
                    tp.Controls.Add(b);
                 }
            }
        }
```

I found a similar issue on Stack Overflow and the reply states it's a syntax error but doesn't point out where.

Comment: You class  CoffeeShopDBEntities  needs to inherit the class System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.  So you should have something like public class CoffeeShopDBEntities : System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext{....}

Comment: thank you jdwing- that's auto created when added ADONet to the project..i'm not so sure if i can do anything about it..

Answer (score 1):

You are getting errors because ObjectQuery is looking for an ObjectContext which comes with EF 4.0 and below. The CoffeeShopDBEntities is of the DBContext type which comes with anything EF 4.1 and above.

I would suggest changing your query to:

```
List<tblProduct> filteredProducts = cse.tblProducts.ToList();
```

If you want to read more on the ObjectContext vs. DBContext, you can check out this link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext/

Comment: thank you very much Miguel, that worked great however i'm not sure how to add the sql statement part of it..it wont take parameters ..

Comment: If you still want to use SQL statements, you could use:

`cse.Database.SqlQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P");`

Comment: thanks alot miguel for lending a hand..yours is the closest i got..i can't seem to put together all the bits and dots of information..the sql statement didn't generate errors nor did anything. i got 3 tabbed pages (each for a category/ProductType) and trying to display the products on each page that belong to the particular category:

Comment: foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
                {   int i = 1;
                    List<tblProduct> filteredProducts = cse.tblProducts.ToList();
                    cse.Database.SqlQuery<tblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM tblProducts AS P WHERE P.ProductType=" + i);
                  FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                    flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    foreach (tblProduct tprod in filteredProducts)
                    {...}

Comment: solved the issue with this:   using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {
        var objectContext = (ctx as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        
        //use objectContext here..
    } that i've found on entityframeworktutorial.net